# Triggering a Meteor method call on a different server sharing the same database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Let's say I have a normal Meteor website/app hosted on Galaxy, and then an admin site hosted on a different server, but **both are connected to the same database**.

I want a user on my regular site to be able to **trigger a method call** (or any procedure) on the admin server remotely.

I'm thinking this can be done because, if I had a *dummy user* logged into the right page on the admin server, then it would listen for changes in whatever collection "he" is subscribed to. If the real user on the different server changes something in that collection, the dummy user would see it, and that could in turn trigger a method call.

Now, there has to be a way to skip the step of the dummy user and listen in on changes directly from the admin server.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction here?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? Why would you choose to "trigger" a method call and not simply run a procedure/worker on server startup that would listen to the relevant database changes and do whatever it is that you are trying to do?

Comment: That's what I want to know how to do.

Comment: OK. Can you explain the use case? I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: From the dummy user part of your question: you could observe changes to your collection on the admin side, if it is just related to data changes, no?  Otherwise I think I would expose a route on your admin app that can be used as a service by your client app, or something along those lines.

Comment: @MasterAM Admin server is responsible for sending out email and querying/updating the database as it does so. A lot of code and work that I don't want to have on my regular server. Doesn't really matter, imagine I just want to print a `console.log("hello")` for the purposes of this question!

Comment: It's probably possible, but won't be worth the hassle.

Just set up an API on the server you'd like to connect to. Have that API do what you'd like and then return. I've used the http-methods package before for just this case:
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods

Comment: You can also use DDP to communicate between the servers. Simpler if using Meteor, IMHO.

Comment: @MasterAM If you think I just need to hear a word from a proposed solution to instantly know what you mean or how to do it, you're mistaken.

Comment: Take a look at [`DDP.connect()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect) and [this discussion](https://forums.meteor.com/t/connecting-2-apps-over-ddp-how-to-login-across/977). I did not know how well you know Meteor, so I had no idea how much detail was needed in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment to OP with some code.

First, add [this package](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods) to the server you have created where you'd like to access some meteor methods, etc. Then:

```
// server1.js
Meteor.methods({
    foo: function(bar) {
        check(bar, Whatever)
        ... do some stuff ...

        return fooBar
    }
})

HTTP.methods({
    '/foo/:bar': function() {
        return JSON.stringify(Meteor.call("foo", this.params.bar), null, '\t')
    }
});
```

Finally, on the other server, where you'd like to access the first server:

```
// server2.js
// somewhere on your server (startup, a method, etc.)
try {
    var bar = ...
    var result = HTTP.call(
        "GET", "http://yourFirstServer.com/foo/" + bar
    )
} catch (e) {
    // Got a network error, time-out or HTTP error in the 400 or 500 range.
    console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: It's just a route. It's essentially a REST API. You'd access it with the code I included in server2.js

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like this is a matter of wanting to have administration operations running from a separate server, with administration code *only* on that server.

If this is indeed what's needed, the simplest way I can think to do it would be to run another instance of the meteor app on the other server, but the 'enhanced' version, and have your admin users connect to that server (perhaps called admin.yourdomain.com).
You can still point the server at the original mongodb (by setting MONGO_URL as appropriate).

Comment: Not quite sure what problem this would solve. I don't need any of the code from my client server on the admin server. And they don't talk to each other just because they're "similar".

Comment: Apologies, I just reread your original post and it makes far more sense. The answer provided by @Adam looks like the right way to go, to me.